# Monacaで公開したAndroidアプリが起動しない

Tags: android

### 相談内容

以下の状況で、アプリが起動しない原因がどこにありそうか、アドバイスをいただければ幸いです。
コードを見ないと断言できないのは承知の上で、一般論だけでもお教えいただきたく質問しました。

アプリの設計なのか、Jacascript等の記述のミスなのか、または端末自体に問題があるのか、など
当たりが付くだけでも助かります。

### 問題・前提

- HTML5ハイブリッドアプリをGoogle Playで公開した
- Monaca公式サンプルをほぼそのまま使った超シンプルな地図アプリ
- 依頼主から「アプリ自体が起動しない」と言われた
- 依頼主の環境は AU、SHARP SHL22、Android 4.2.2
- ランチャーにアイコンは出ているという
- アンインストール＆再インストール、端末再起動などは試してみた
- 自前のテスト用Android端末2台と、知人の端末5台では正しく動作していた
- 全く同じコードのiPhone版アプリは5台以上で動作が確認されている

Comment: `自前のテスト用Android端末2台と、知人の端末5台では正しく動作していた`とありますが、OSバージョンは確認しましたか？依頼主と同じ端末やOSバージョンで確認した方がよろしいかと思います。私が開発したアプリも、いきなり★1を食らったことがあるので、特定の端末で動作しない場合も考えられます。

Comment: Android4.2.2 という古い端末が用意できず、参っています。
このような場合、バグの原因を探すことは困難でしょうか。

Comment: 私はGenymotionを使用してデバッグを行っています。 https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Genymotion、藁にもすがる思いでインストールしてみました。
少しでも糸口が掴めれば何よりです。

Answer (score 1):

Monacaがどうしているかは分かりませんが、
apkへの証明書の署名方法によっては古い端末で起動しない可能性があります。
Androidの証明書(keystore証明書)は保存しておりますか？
そちらでAPKを再度署名しなおしては如何でしょう？

私の環境はMacですが下記のようにターミナルより署名しております。
(※署名には[JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)が必要です)

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ./keystore.private ~/Desktop/android.apk 【証明書を発行しているメールアドレス】
```